# Perform an operation on a vector using the previous value after an initial value

Tags: r

In Excel, it's easy to perform a calculation on a previous cell by referencing that earlier cell.  For example, starting from an initial value of 100 (step = 0), each next step would be `0.9 * previous + 9` simply by dragging the formula bar down from the first cell (step = 1).  The next 10 steps would look like:

```
      step     value
 [1,]    0 100.00000
 [2,]    1  99.00000
 [3,]    2  98.10000
 [4,]    3  97.29000
 [5,]    4  96.56100
 [6,]    5  95.90490
 [7,]    6  95.31441
 [8,]    7  94.78297
 [9,]    8  94.30467
[10,]    9  93.87420
[11,]   10  93.48678
```

I've looked around the web and StackOverflow, and the best I could come up with is a `for` loop (below).  Are there more efficient ways to do this?  Is it possible to avoid a `for` loop?  It seems like most functions in R (such as `cumsum`, `diff`, `apply`, etc) work on existing vectors instead of calculating new values on the fly from previous ones.

```
#for loop.  This works
value <- 100   #Initial value
for(i in 2:11) {
  current <- 0.9 * value[i-1] + 9
  value <- append(value, current)
}
cbind(step = 0:10, value)  #Prints the example output shown above
```

Comment: Do not use `append`. Preallocate `value` to the final size and assign to its elements. Growing an object is one of the slowest operations you can do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a way to do recursive calculations in R.  Base R has two ways of doing this which differ by the form of the function used to do the recursion.  Both methods could be used for your example.

`Reduce` can be used with recursion equations of the form `v[i+1]  =  function(v[i], x[i])` where `v` is the calculated vector and `x` an input vector; i.e. where the `i+1` output depends only the i-th values of the calculated and input vectors and the calculation performed by `function(v, x)` may be nonlinear. For you case, this would be

```
    value <- 100
    nout <- 10
# v[i+1]  =  function(v[i], x[i])
    v <- Reduce(function(v, x) .9*v  + 9, x=numeric(nout),  init=value, accumulate=TRUE)
    cbind(step = 0:nout, v)
```

`filter` is used with recursion equations of the form  `y[i+1] = x[i] + filter[1]*y[i-1] + ... + filter[p]*y[i-p]` where `y` is the calculated vector and `x` an input vector; i.e. where the output can depend linearly upon lagged values of the calculated vector as well as the `i-th` value of the input vector. For your case, this would be:

```
    value <- 100
     nout <- 10
# y[i+1] = x[i] + filter[1]*y[i-1] + ... + filter[p]*y[i-p]
        y <- c(value, stats::filter(x=rep(9, nout), filter=.9, method="recursive", sides=1, init=value))
     cbind(step = 0:nout, y)
```

For both functions, the length of the output is given by the length of the input vector `x`.
Both of these approaches give your result.

Answer (score 9):

Use our knowledge about the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series).

```
i <- 0:10
0.9 ^ i * 100 + 9 * (0.9 ^ i - 1) / (0.9 - 1)
#[1] 100.00000  99.00000  98.10000  97.29000  96.56100  95.90490  95.31441  94.78297  94.30467  93.87420  93.48678
```

Comment: Great answer (+1) @Roland!  I chose @WaltS's answer because it is more flexible such as in cases where the constants are actually variables themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `purrr::accumulate`:

```
data.frame(value = purrr::accumulate(0:10, ~ .x * .9 + 9, .init = 100))

       value
1  100.00000
2   99.00000
3   98.10000
4   97.29000
5   96.56100
6   95.90490
7   95.31441
8   94.78297
9   94.30467
10  93.87420
11  93.48678
12  93.13811
```

`.init` is the initial value and there is also the argument `.dir` if you want to control the direction ("forward" is the default)