# In R, how do I make an iterative calculation without using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, iteration, shift

Here is a simple example of one type of iterative calc:

```
vals <- data.frame( "x"=c( 14, 15, 12, 10, 17 ), "ema"=0 )
vals$ema[1] <- vals$x[1]
K <- 0.90
for( jj in 2:nrow( vals ) )
  vals$ema[jj] <- K * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K) * vals$x[jj]

vals
   x     ema
1 14 14.0000
2 15 14.1000
3 12 13.8900
4 10 13.5010
5 17 13.8509
```

The more involved examples use if...else to determine the next value:

```
for( jj in 2:nrow( vals ) )
    if( K * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K) * vals$x[jj] < 5.0 )
        vals$ema[jj] <- 5.0
    else if( K * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K) * vals$x[jj] > 15.0 )
        vals$ema[jj] <- 15.0
    else
        vals$ema[jj] <- K * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K) * vals$x[jj]
```

I am not sure if it would be more involved or not, but the decision can be based on the previous value as well:

```
K1 <- 0.999
K2 <- 0.95
K3 <- 0.90
for( jj in 2:now( vals ) )
    if( vals$ema[jj-1] < 0.0 )
        vals$ema[jj] <- K1 * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K1) * vals$x[jj]
    else if( vals$ema[jj-1] > 100.0 )
        vals$ema[jj] <- K3 * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K3) * vals$x[jj]
    else
        vals$ema[jj] <- K2 * vals$ema[jj-1] + (1-K2) * vals$x[jj]
```

Comment: Since neither of the answers I received solved the problem, I went looking in the TTR package, which does EMA's and it does them faster than a loop in R.  What TTR does is drop into C and loop there: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/TTR/blob/master/src/moving_averages.c  My question is still the same: can you make an iterative calculation in R without using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704226/4718512) by WaltS to a similar question I had about recursive calculations provides two potential solutions. Adapting one of them to your question:

```
vals$ema.Reduce <- Reduce(function(myema, x) K * myema + (1-K) * x, 
                          x =  tail(vals$x, -1), init = 14, accumulate = TRUE)
vals
#   x     ema ema.Reduce
#1 14 14.0000    14.0000
#2 15 14.1000    14.1000
#3 12 13.8900    13.8900
#4 10 13.5010    13.5010
#5 17 13.8509    13.8509
```

Explanation of the function:

`Reduce()` is calculating ema for the current jj row, and *myema* is the previous value (jj-1) starting with `init`. The *x* vector required by `Reduce` consists of vals$x for the rows you want to calculate: row 2 to the last row = `x = tail(vals$x, -1)`. The `accumulate = TRUE` option returns the vector instead of the final value. (Note the *x* term in `Reduce` is a generic term and not the same as vals$x in the example data. For calculations that do not require the additional term vals$x, a vector of 0's would work (as in the linked answer)).

Adding if/else conditions to `Reduce` (note: `init` is changed in these examples to illustrate the conditional statements):

```
Reduce(function(myema, x) {
    if(myema < 5) {
      5
    } else if(myema > 15) {
      15
    } else {
      K * myema + (1-K) * x
    }
  }, x =  tail(vals$x, -1), init = 16, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 16.000 15.000 14.700 14.230 14.507

Reduce(function(myema, x) {
    if(myema < 0) {
      K1 * myema + (1-K1) * x
    } else if(myema > 100) {
      K3 * myema + (1-K3) * x
    } else {
      K2 * myema + (1-K2) * x
    }
  }, x =  tail(vals$x, -1), init = 110, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 110.00000 100.50000  91.65000  87.56750  84.03912

K3*110     + (1-K3)*vals$x[2] #100.5
K3*100.5   + (1-K3)*vals$x[3] #91.65
K2*91.65   + (1-K2)*vals$x[4] #87.5675
K2*87.5675 + (1-K2)*vals$x[5] #84.03912
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the detailed reply.  I didn't know that LISP called this a Reduce, but maybe if I had asked for a Fold or an Accumulate, someone would have been able to answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this succeeds:

```
vals$ema2 <- c(vals$ema[1], K*vals$ema[1:4] +(1-K)*vals$x[2:5] )

> vals
   x     ema    ema2
1 14 14.0000 14.0000
2 15 14.1000 14.1000
3 12 13.8900 13.8900
4 10 13.5010 13.5010
5 17 13.8509 13.8509
```

Comment: or say `vals$ema2 <- c(vals$ema[1], K*vals$ema[1:(nrow(vals)-1)] +(1-K)*vals$x[2:nrow(vals)] )`

Comment: The OP (confusingly) overwrote ema in the loop that they want you to replace; it really starts as 14 all the way down (if you run the code up until just before the for loop).

Comment: Both of these answers that refer to vals$ema are referring to the answer to calculate vals$ema2.  I want to refer only to vals$x--or an ema value that was not previously calculated.

Comment: This does not work:  vals$ema2 <- c(vals$x[1], K*vals$ema2[1:now(vans)-1] +(1-K)*vals$x[2:now(vals)]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is best to work with the time series and data munging libraries. In this case, lag.zoo from the zoo library handles lagged values for you.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
vals <- data.frame( "x"=c( 14, 15, 12, 10, 17 ) )
K <- 0.90
vals %>% mutate(ema = (1-K)*vals$x + K*(lag(vals$x,1)))
```

Comment: This does not work.  You are using vals$x in both the 1-K and the K portion of the equation.  This is an iterative calculation: the 1-K portion is supposed to used the previously calculated value of ema.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, the weights for each value is some function of `k` and `i` (as in the `i`th value).  We can write a function for the weights, and vectorize it:

```
weights <- function(i, k) {
    q <- 1-k
    qs <- '^'(q, 1:i)
    rev(qs) * c(1, rep(k, (i-1)))
}
v_weights <- Vectorize(weights)
```

An example:

```
> v_weights(1:3, .1)
[[1]]
[1] 0.9

[[2]]
[1] 0.81 0.09

[[3]]
[1] 0.729 0.081 0.090
```

where these are the weights of the "preceding" `x` values. We proceed with some matrix algebra.  I write a function to make the weights (above) into a matrix:

```
weight_matrix <- function(j, k) {
    w <- v_weights(1:j, k=k)
    Ws <- matrix(0, j+1, j+1)
    Ws[row(Ws)+col(Ws)<(j+2)] <- unlist(rev(w))
    Ws <- t(Ws)
    Ws[row(Ws)+col(Ws)==(j+2)] <- k
    Ws[(j+1),1] <- 1
    Ws
}
```

Example:

```
> weight_matrix(3, .1)
      [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.729 0.081 0.09  0.1
[2,] 0.810 0.090 0.10  0.0
[3,] 0.900 0.100 0.00  0.0
[4,] 1.000 0.000 0.00  0.0
```

Then multiply this with the vector of `x`s.  Function: `ema <- function(x, k) rev(weight_matrix(length(x)-1, k) %*% x[1:(length(x))])`.

To get the dataframe above (I "flipped" the `k` so it's 0.1 instead of 0.9):

```
> x <- c(14, 15, 12, 10, 17)
> k <- .1
> vals <- data.frame("x"=x, "ema"=ema(x, k))
> vals
   x     ema
1 14 14.0000
2 15 14.1000
3 12 13.8900
4 10 13.5010
5 17 13.8509
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but a bit complicated.  How would you apply it to the more involved examples, where you do not know the factor to apply until you have calculated the previous value?

Comment: Most of the work is wrangling the matrix into the right form -- otherwise it's just linear algebra. Having thought about it a bit, I think your original question -- how to make an iterative calculation without using a loop -- really depends on the specific calculation you want to make, so every solution is going to be fairly bespoke. I do think my solution to your simplest example is the only one here that satisfies your requirement that "I want to refer only to `vals$x`--or an ema value that was not previously calculated." :)

Comment: [This article](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html) suggests instances in which vectorization may be particularly profitable.  I do think some of the other answers here are quite elegant and functional, even though there is implicit looping.

Answer (score 0):

@shayaa's answer is 99% correct. `dplyr` implements `lag` just fine, and apart from a typo in that answer (one value of `x` should be `ema`), extraneous calls to column names, and a missing default value (otherwise it puts `NA` in the first row) it works perfectly well.

```
library(dplyr)
vals %>% mutate(ema = K*lag(ema, 1, default=ema[1]) + (1-K)*x)
#>    x     ema
#> 1 14 14.0000
#> 2 15 14.1000
#> 3 12 13.8900
#> 4 10 13.5010
#> 5 17 13.8509
```

Comment: Worth to learn `base` R before suggesting heavy `dplyr` everywhere.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Just because `base` was there first doesn't make it the better tool for every job. This is hardly heavy, and simplifies the answer significantly.

Comment: Is there a bug in your answer?  When I run against: > vals x ema 1 14 14 2 15 0 3 12 0 4 10 0 5 17 0 I get an answer of: x ema 1 14 14.0 2 15 14.1 3 12 1.2 4 10 1.0 5 17 1.7.  It seems like you pre-loaded the ema column first.  Your code uses the old values of ema, which start out as zero, except for the first slot.  From what I can tell, this does not work.