# How do I make an iterative calculation without using a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have a "big" data frame where I need to do a calcul like below :

```
data <- data.frame( "name"=c( "Tom", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Tom", "Peter" ), "goal"=c(1,-2,2,3,-1,0), "total"=0 )
for( i in 1:nrow(data) ) {
  count <- 0
  for ( j in 1:i) {
    if (data$name[j] == data$name[i]) {
      count <- count + data$goal[j]
    }
  }
  data$total[i] <- count
}

> data
   name goal total
1   Tom    1     1
2 Peter   -2    -2
3  John    2     2
4 Peter    3     1
5   Tom   -1     0
6 Peter    0     1
```

I need to perform the calculation of the "total" column by adding the goals scored before.

My database is currently 83000 rows long and the calculation is very long. I would like to do this calculation without a "for" loop. Do you have an idea ?

I saw the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627066/in-r-how-do-i-make-an-iterative-calculation-without-using-a-loop) but I don't know how to adapt it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `for` loops, try to find vectorized functions that do what you want. (Or functions working on dataframes or other multidimensional objects).
For your example you can separate the dataframe according to `name` using `group_by` from `dplyr` and then use the vectorized function `cumsum` (cumulative sum):

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(total = cumsum(goal))
```

Output

```
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
  name   goal total
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tom       1     1
2 Peter    -2    -2
3 Peter     2     0
4 Peter     3     3
5 Tom      -1     0
6 Peter     0     3
```

I used your dataframe initialization in your post, which is why I get a different output than yours.

If you want to drop the grouping after your manipulation, use `ungroup`.